# Python - whats the most efficient way to read large multi sheet spreadsheets into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a directory full of large spreadsheets.
My plan is to read each of the sheets into a dataframe, drop what I dont need and remove duplicates, then append to a master dataframe that I will then save as an excell file.

My current method like the following...

```
for workbook in filelist:
        For sheet in workbook:
           Df = pd.read_excell(workbook, sheet)
          ## Do table manipulation and append to master df
```

My problem is it takes a long time, I'm concerned that everytime I loop it is opening and closing the workbook.

Is there a way I can open the workbook and then cycle through each sheet saving it to a dataframe?

Note, the column headers are the same on each sheet.

Apologise for the shorthand code up there,I'm afk.

Comment: The problem with pseudocode in this case is that example running python code isn't really much larger and wouldn't have to guess about what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the workbook once and read sheets from it. I don't know if this is really any faster, but worth a try

```
import pandas as pd

for filename in filelist:
    workbook = pd.ExcelFile()
    for sheet in workbook.sheet_names:
        df = workbook.parse(sheet)
```

Comment: Does workbook.parse work like read_excel? So each loop df is been overwritten with a new sheet, just checking :p

Comment: Their function signatures are very close. My guess is that `read_excel` does `ExcelFile(engine=engine).parse(...)` but there are a few parameters that are different, so maybe not. I haven't looked at the source. You can do `help(pd.ExcelFile)` to see if there any fields you need that are missing in the call.

Comment: @MartynBell - df keeps getting assigned a new dataframe on each round of the loop. I assume you process and store each one in the loop itself. And technically, its not "overwritten" its reassigned a new dataframe so you don't have to worry about frame saved somewhere else being modified by the new assignment.

Comment: you can use `pd.read_excel(sheet_name=None)` which reads in the entire workbook as an ordered dictionary, then you parse all the sheets from the dictionary object.

Comment: @Datanovice how do i then merge the dict values?
each dict value will have the columns headers and values

Comment: you can concat, but are you concenating each sheet from all the dicts, so `Sheet1` from n number of excel workbooks?  if that's the case let me know and i'll update this answer if it's cool with @tdelaney

Comment: @Datanovice - Sure. I didn't delve into what happens to the df. If the question is updated to let us know what happens to the df in the long run, then feel free to update the answer. We need to wait for OP to make sure we aren't just guessing.